# Can I use youtube-viewer on ubuntu18.04

Tags: youtube, 18.04

I used to use ubuntu 16.04 ,but now it's 18.04 .

youtube-dl still working , but youtube-viewer can't work

I had reinstalled it , but command line showed that the ppa didn't had any release .

Is it possible to use youtube-viewer in future ?

Comment: You'll have to ask the developer of the software for a definite answer. Try at launchpad.net.

Comment: so sad , I love youtube-viewer .

Comment: It's so convinient

Comment: What is the name of the youtube-viewer and a link to the PPA?  I'll see what I can find in my 18.04 environment.

Comment: I added the ppa via author's github
https://github.com/trizen/youtube-viewer

Comment: In the column AVAILABILITY , you could find the ppa 
nilarimogard/webupd8

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1045046/66509 for solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sudo apt install git libncurses5-dev libtinfo-dev libreadline-dev pkg-config libgtk2.0-dev libcanberra-gtk-module
```

Either downloading the zip from github (https://github.com/trizen/youtube-viewer) or using git clone

```
$ git clone https://github.com/trizen/youtube-viewer     
$ cd youtube-viewer
$ sudo cpan install CPAN ExtUtils::PkgConfig Module::Build inc::latest PAR::Dist Term::ReadLine::Gnu::XS Unicode::GCString LWP::Protocol::https Data::Dump JSON Gtk2 File::ShareDir
$ perl Build.PL --gtk
$ sudo ./Build installdeps
$ sudo ./Build install
```

Then, done.

```
$ gtk-youtube-viewer
```