# How to make youtube-viewer zip package installable for 18.04

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, youtube, perl

I've recently upgraded to 18.04 and miss youtube-viewer which is not in the repo (yet??). [This thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029038/can-i-use-youtube-viewer-on-ubuntu18-04) has an answer in which the poster says they got it working by downloading youtube-viewer-master.zip from github (https://github.com/trizen/youtube-viewer) "followed by a few installation steps to finish it up."

I'm relatively new to Ubuntu and Perl but I want to see if I can get it working.  So far I have run `perl Build.PL`, and satisfied several dependencies + changed folder permissions to allow the scripts to complete further.

The last terminal lines were:

```
    Configuring H/HA/HAYASHI/Term-ReadLine-Gnu-1.35.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
    Could not find neither libtermcap.a, libncurses.a, or libcurses.
    Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site]
      HAYASHI/Term-ReadLine-Gnu-1.35.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- NOT OK
```

I installed libcurses-perl with Synaptic + re-ran it, but got the same result. I could not find libtermcap.a or libncurses.a in Synaptic.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Difficult way (you chose it)

It seems that you need to install the following packages

1. for [libtermcap.a](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&searchon=contents&keywords=libtermcap.a)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libtinfo-dev
   ```
2. for [libncurses.a](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&section=all&arch=amd64&keywords=libncurses.a&searchon=contents)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
   ```
3. the it may need [readline/readdline.h](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&section=all&arch=amd64&keywords=readline.h&searchon=contents), installable with

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev
   ```

Do not forget to install Unicode::GCString with `sudo apt-get install libunicode-linebreak-perl`.

Complete method is as follows:

```
cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/trizen/youtube-viewer
cd youtube-viewer

sudo apt-get install libmodule-build-perl libtinfo-dev \
libncurses5-dev libreadline-dev libunicode-linebreak-perl

perl Build.PL --gtk
sudo ./Build installdeps  # hit <Enter> everywhere
sudo ./Build install

gtk-youtube-viewer # run it
```

It will be installed in */usr/local*: executables are placed in */usr/local/bin* - */usr/local/bin/gtk-youtube-viewer* and */usr/local/bin/youtube-viewer*.

---

## Correct way

Wait for deb-package.

Update 2018-10-06: I sent packaging request to the [ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8?field.series_filter=bionic) owner - [Alin Andrei via launchpad](https://launchpad.net/%7Enilarimogard/+contactuser).

Comment: I did 'the hard way' cuz I want to learn in addition to getting the package onto the system. It worked + I appreciate ur time to write out the steps. Now that it's installed, can I delete the youtube-viewer directory in Downloads, or is that still necessary for it to run? I looked in /bin and /usr/bin and didn't see it in either one.  I don't know how this works- has this process created an executable file somewhere that I can share with others, use on another 18.04 machine, and / or offer back to Alin and save him a little bit of work? Thx.

Comment: You can delete folder in *~Downloads*, executables are placed in */usr/local/bin* - */usr/local/bin/gtk-youtube-viewer* and */usr/local/bin/youtube-viewer*, other stuff installed to subdirectories of */usr/local*. I wrote an a message to Alin via LaunchPad.

Comment: Thx - last question: are the executables portable? I have 3 other machines that I'll upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04.  If it's not in repo, can one simply copy the executables from this build into the same directory on another machine; or should I do the perl build on each machine.

Comment: I have never tried to package Perl-dependent stuff. So I do not know about portability. We can wait for PPA packages then...

Comment: OK that makes sense.  Thx for all your time.